# Pandas: ValueError when pivoting dataframe with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following code, the point of which is to pivot a SQL table retrieved from an Oracle database:

```
s = "SELECT Country || '_' || Product || '_' || Flow Ref, " + \
        "Country, Product, Flow, zm, Qty " + \
    "FROM Volumes "

#Following will simply pull from db into a dataframe 
df = fb.QueryDB(s)

#Put ZM as column headers
df = df.pivot(values = 'QTY', index = 'REF', columns = 'ZM')

#Format the column headers
df.columns = [x.strftime('%b-%Y') for x in df.columns]
```

It all works great, and i get a dataframe such as:

```
         Mar-2017    Apr-2017
 Ref
A_B_C      100          110
D_E_F      500          210
G_H_I      310          150
```

Except now i want to create a multi-index, as follows:

```
                                    Mar-2017    Apr-2017
 Ref    Country   Product   Flow
A_B_C     A          B       C        100          110
D_E_F     D          E       F        500          210
G_H_I     G          H       I        310          150
```

To do this i edit the line for pivoting the dataframe to:

```
df = df.pivot(values = 'QTY', index = ['REF','COUNTRY','PRODUCT','FLOW'], columns = 'ZM')
```

This produces the following error

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1859796, placement implies 4

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
data = {'REF' : ['A_B_C','D_E_F','G_H_I','A_B_C','D_E_F','G_H_I'],
        'COUNTRY' : list('ADGADG'),
        'PRODUCT' : list('BEHBEH'),
        'FLOW' : list('CFICFI'),
         'QTY':[100,500,310,110,210,150],
         'ZM':pd.to_datetime(['2017-03-01'] * 3 + ['2017-04-01'] * 3 )}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
  COUNTRY FLOW PRODUCT  QTY    REF         ZM
0       A    C       B  100  A_B_C 2017-03-01
1       D    F       E  500  D_E_F 2017-03-01
2       G    I       H  310  G_H_I 2017-03-01
3       A    C       B  110  A_B_C 2017-04-01
4       D    F       E  210  D_E_F 2017-04-01
5       G    I       H  150  G_H_I 2017-04-01

df = df.set_index(['REF','COUNTRY','PRODUCT','FLOW', 'ZM'])['QTY']
       .unstack()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%b-%Y')
print (df)
                            Mar-2017  Apr-2017
REF   COUNTRY PRODUCT FLOW                    
A_B_C A       B       C          100       110
D_E_F D       E       F          500       210
G_H_I G       H       I          310       150
```

---

If it return error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function which is apply if duplicates:

```
data = {'REF' : ['A_B_C','A_B_C','G_H_I','A_B_C','D_E_F','G_H_I'],
        'COUNTRY' : list('AAGADG'),
        'PRODUCT' : list('BBHBEH'),
        'FLOW' : list('CCICFI'),
         'QTY':[100,500,310,110,210,150],
         'ZM':pd.to_datetime(['2017-03-01'] * 3 + ['2017-04-01'] * 3 )}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
  COUNTRY FLOW PRODUCT  QTY    REF         ZM
0       A    C       B  100  A_B_C 2017-03-01 <-dupe COUNTRY,FLOW,PRODUCT,QTY,REF 
1       A    C       B  500  A_B_C 2017-03-01 <-dupe COUNTRY,FLOW,PRODUCT,QTY,REF 
2       G    I       H  310  G_H_I 2017-03-01
3       A    C       B  110  A_B_C 2017-04-01
4       D    F       E  210  D_E_F 2017-04-01
5       G    I       H  150  G_H_I 2017-04-01


df = df.pivot_table(values = 'QTY', 
                    index = ['REF','COUNTRY','PRODUCT','FLOW'], 
                    columns = 'ZM', 
                    aggfunc='mean')

df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%b-%Y')
print (df)
                            Mar-2017  Apr-2017
REF   COUNTRY PRODUCT FLOW                    
A_B_C A       B       C        300.0     110.0
D_E_F D       E       F          NaN     210.0
G_H_I G       H       I        310.0     150.0
```

Or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `aggregate function` + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['REF','COUNTRY','PRODUCT','FLOW', 'ZM'])['QTY'].mean().unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%b-%Y')
print (df)
                            Mar-2017  Apr-2017
REF   COUNTRY PRODUCT FLOW                    
A_B_C A       B       C        300.0     110.0
D_E_F D       E       F          NaN     210.0
G_H_I G       H       I        310.0     150.0
```

Comment: Option #1 worked. Option #2 created a ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Yes both pivot_table worked, but i should point out that i had a mistake above, and so i needed to replace ZM with FLOW in your code. Thank you.

Comment: Super, I edit it. `df.set_index(['REF','COUNTRY','PRODUCT','FLOW', 'ZM'])['QTY'].unstack()` works also?